# Use depth of field only for some objects and not for others

Tags: blur, depth-of-field

I am using depth of field, that is connected from camera to object, but I want to not cause blur efect for 2 other objects, is it even possible?

Comment: You will have to render them separately, then joining the two renders using the compositor.

Comment: @Dudzioo Composite with Z-Combine or Cryptomatte? BTW May I ask for what reason?